# NEO4J Server: Update nodes

Tags: neo4j

I'm using neo4j server versión 1.8. The current requirement of my application is to create and/or update multiple nodes and add them to a specific index (all in one request). We have several indexes, and one node can be in some of them. Those nodes have a property that is a ID (significant for our application). If there is already a node with that ID, we only need to override its properties. What we now do is to first check which of these nodes exist (via GET in the index that contains all the nodes) and stored in a data structure. Then I make the batch request to create or update the nodes. If the ID does not exist in the data structure, we have to create a node. Otherwise, only we have to update its properties. This is slow, it is best to make a batch request only, instead of two. I try with UNIQUE INDEXES but the node can be in several indexes. What do you recommend I do?

Comment: what do you mean with it is slow? what processing time do you have now and what processing time you would like to have? also, do you use any specific library, REST, neo4jphp, py2neo?

Comment: I use the REST API from Java. The process I describe lasts about 25 seconds on my development machine for the creation/update of 2500 nodes. I hope to cut that time in half. I think that it will be achieved if instead of two batch requests all the process can be made in one. As I said before, the first request I make is, based on a list of IDs meaningful to my application, check if existing nodes containing one of these IDs. If they already exist, I store the ID meaningful to our application and its URI in a data structure. The next request is the one responsible for the creation/update.

Comment: look into batching rest requests with Neo4j, with that you can do node creation in one request and adding those created nodes to the indexes you want in a second request: http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-batch-ops.html

Comment: there is a feature in cypher called "create unique", maybe you would like to use that or similar feature directly in the REST to do the whole thing in one batch.

Comment: Michael: I'm using batching rest requests. The problem is not adding the created nodes in the indexes. The challenge is check if already exist a node with certain property (a significant ID for my application) and depending on this make a decision if I have to create or update the node. Actually, I do two batching requests as I explain in the question. Thank you!

Comment: ulkas: I found a similar feature called 'UNIQUE INDEXES' as I said in the question, but if already exists a node, the latter is not updated.